# Are some Free VPN services secure or not?

Tags: exploit, vpn, vulnerability

After deciding to be security engineer, everything that I do, for example visiting pages, downloading any content or apps, etc. seems suspicious. So today I encountered something strange in my new VPN.

I heard about a free and secure VPN service [www.urban-vpn.com](https://www.urban-vpn.com/). Firstly, their page uses Lets Encrypt, maybe there is no any remarkable at first glance, but it looks weird for such a service, I think. There is no contact section or any support.

After installing it to my PC and phone,  I tested my phone. Some ports which made me suspicious about being open are:

```
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
135/tcp  open  msrpc
443/tcp  open  https
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
902/tcp  open  iss-realsecure
912/tcp  open  apex-mesh
5357/tcp open  wsdapi'
```

Mostly port 135 took my attention about security of my PC. There were only 2 -3 ports active before installing the VPN.

Personally, I think this service is not secure and I even think they can use my
workstation to make a bot.

So what do you think? Is this kind of VPN service secure or insecure?

Comment: The question in the title is "Are some free VPN services secure?" while the question in the body is "Is it a sign of compromise that port 135 is open?" - the two are radically different.

Comment: You title is completely unrelated to your question (and the title by itself should get the question closed as this site is not for giving recommendations).

Comment: No actually question is in title.Because after installing VPN this and so on ports has opened.So question is clear  that such VPNs are secure or not? (Because i did't exploit any port or service yet.)

Comment: An open port after installing a software is not a sign that your device is compromised, per se. So nobody is going to give you a clear answer here, you should analyse the VPN software to check what service is actually listening on this port and this can be a complex task — that nobody here is going to do for you. You might find this link interresting too: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24252/how-to-figure-out-which-open-ports-or-services-are-insecure

Comment: Thanks .i know taht is complex to answer and same time to say secure or not.But question is actually such a SERVICES reliable or not? THAT MAYBE ANYONE HERE USES SUCH a services. .ThanksAgain @JulesLamur

Comment: Are some VPN services secure? Yes. Are some insecure? Yes. Is it concerning that this VPN has no way to contact them, has no support, and uses free TLS certs? Absolutely. Does that mean the service is insecure? No, but maybe. Does port 135 mean that you are now part of a botnet? No, but maybe.

Comment: @schroeder Thanks..Sure VPNs are secure like ExpressVPN.But some of these are provides absolutely free VPN. .To opening  port 135 leads me thinking about RPC like atacks.And even this port is open in my android after install.So i cant trust actuallay .Thats why i asked pepole who maybe uses and know  and maybe   anaylzed before i asked.Thanks again.